# Cannot assign must be a instance

Tags: python, django

I want to make an insert into 2 tables: CostItems and CostElements, CostElements has cost_item as a foreignkey from CostItems, but when i run it shows me this error message:

> Cannot assign "22": "CostElements.cost_item" must be a "CostItems"
>   instance.

Heres is my code:

Models.py :

```
class CostItems(ModelAudit):
    cost_item = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Item de costo')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, verbose_name = 'Grupo')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name =' Descripcion')
    usd_value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name ='Valor en USD')
    rer = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'TRM')
    pesos_value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Valor en pesos')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, verbose_name = 'Proveedor')
    position = models.ForeignKey(Positions, verbose_name = 'Cargo')
    observations = models.TextField(max_length = 500, verbose_name = 'Observación')
    validity_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Fecha de vigencia')

class CostElements(ModelAudit):
    cost_element = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Elemento de costo')
    cost_item = models.ForeignKey(CostItems, verbose_name = 'Item de costo')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Descripción')
    usd_value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Valor en USD')
    pesos_value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Valor en pesos')
    percent = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Porcentaje de peso')
```

Views.py:

```
class CostItemInsert(View):
    template_name='cost_control_app/home.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.has_perm('cost_control_app.add_costitems'):
            form_insert = CostItemsForm(request.POST)
            if form_insert.is_valid():
                form_save = form_insert.save(commit = False)
                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                des = form_save.description,
                usd = form_save.usd_value,
                pes = form_save.pesos_value,
                form_save.save(force_insert = True) 
                ci= get_object_or_404(CostItems, cost_item=form_save.cost_item)
                cost_element_created = CostElements.objects.create(
                            description = des,
                            percent = 100,
                            usd_value = usd,
                            pesos_value = pes,
                            cost_item = ci.cost_item
                        )

                messages.success(request, "Item de costo creado con exíto")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:cost_item'))   
            else:
                messages.error(request, "No se pudo guardar el registro")
                return render(request, self.template_name,{
                                                            "form_cost_item":form_insert,
                                                          })
        else:
            messages.error(request, "No tienes permisos para esta acción")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:home'))
```

22 itś already a created CostItem ID after form_save.save(force_insert=true), i don't know why it doesn't work, please help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the **shortcut** `get_object_or_404`, according to the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/), the returned object is already an instace of the Model you're working with. In this case, a `CostItems` object.

That means you should use the object returned directly.
Right now you are passing `ci.cost_item` as a parameter. However, `cost_item` is a field in `CostItems` model. Therefore, you are passing that field as a parameter, and not the whole instance.

Consequently, Django raises that error. As aforementioned, you should use the whole instance of `CostItem` in order to make the code work.

Your code should be something like

```
ci= get_object_or_404(CostItems, cost_item=form_save.cost_item)
cost_element_created = CostElements.objects.create(
                            description = des,
                            percent = 100,
                            usd_value = usd,
                            pesos_value = pes,
                            cost_item = ci)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i already tried that but i get this error :

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

With the first one making a trace, it receives 22, but says itś no instance of CostItems....dunno what to do, just doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @jsanchezs I'm sure you have to pass `ci` as the parameter. The error raised after that has nothing to do with it. Pay attention at this: you have to pass the same `type` of object you have defined in your Model. So, if you defined an `IntegerField` there, you should pass an `integer`; If you defined a field as a `CharField`, you should pass a string etc. Check if you are passing the correct types of objects as the parameters. Check the types of these variables : `des`, `usd`, `pes` and check if they match the defined types.

Comment: Solved it, removing comas from  the variable assignation before form_save.save and it worked. Thank s a lot man !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just took out the "comas" of the variable assignation before form_save.save and it worked.

Thanks Rafael